# Apache Aliased Directory doesn't work for child directories of alias

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, .htaccess, directory

I'm trying to run two different applications under user.

> Application 1: /home/user/public_html/app/public/
>
> Application 2: /home/user/public_html/forum/

VirtualHost has the Server set to the root domain, and the document root set to `/home/user/public_html/app/public` (because that's what needs to appear at the root)

At the end of my site.conf, I have the following (outside of the virtualhost, I've tried both in and out, with and without trailing slash)

```
Alias /forum/ /home/user/public_html/forum/
<Directory /home/user/public_html/forum>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

The alias for **just /forum/** works flawlessly, however if I try to navigate to `/forum/settings/` I'm moved back into Application 1's directory and given a 404 there.

How do I get this alias to work for all children? (Children in this case are queries through `index.php`, which are run through `.htaccess`)

Comment: What is the query, and what do the access and error logs show, for the request giving the 404?

Comment: It is two laravel installations. So all traffic should be forwarded through index.php for each. So anything outside of the /forum/ directive goes to the root laravel install. Is that what you're asking? Nothing unusual is in the logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. If you do a separate apache virtualhost and set the server name to be the sub-folder, it will redirect all traffic through that virtual host.

```
ServerName example.com/subfolder
DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html/forum
```